# how to calculate width and height of mobile device

Tags: css, ios, html, android-layout, web-applications

i want to create a div under document.body.
The width and height of that div should be such that
it exactly fits the mobile device, now that device can be
a tablet like an ipad or a mobile deivce like iPhone, or any web page on
desktop browsers.
i tried with screen.width, and screen.height, but these values are not
exactly equal to device width and height!
then empirically i tried subtracting some number form it , and got 18 which 
avoid scrolls on document.body when width and height of that div = sreen.width and screen.height.
but even this numbers are not consitent on all browsers.

I also have one more question, on iphone if we change the view from portrait to landscape,
why does the font size change ?
i have this meta tag on the html page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [PHP browser detection library](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/)

It provides lot of information about OS, browser, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
var w = $(document).width();
var h = $(document).height();
//your div, for example with class 'loremIpsum', will get exactly that sizes with:
$('div.loremIpsum').width(w).height(h);
```